# How to properly get value from a check_box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get a value from a checked `check_box` that is not a column in the model. The variable is always `nil`, however. What exactly am I doing wrong?

_form.html.erb

```
<%= survey_form.check_box :end_time_check, :class => 'checkbox show-toggle' , :data => { :target => "#end-time" }%>
```

survey.rb

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :end_time_check
....
before_validation :doSomething
```

EDIT: Controller

```
params.require(:survey).permit(..., :end_time_check)
```

EDIT2: usage in Survey.rb

```
def doSomething
  if self.end_time_check 
    //do something
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have permited the end_time_check param on controller?

Comment: Yes, I forgot and thought that this will solve the problem for sure. However, nothing has changed

Comment: The form is sending the correct parameters, the problem is most likely in how I am accessing them...

Comment: If the params where came from the request are valid, the problem can be on your validation. Use the the [pry gem](https://github.com/pry/pry), or something, to check where you lose the value.

Comment: Use @ instead self to properties

Comment: I am working on existing project, and follow the style they have. Anyway, I found the problem. I thought I am checking the value before validation, but it happened in `after_initialize` where the values are not yet available, as I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set a attribute as value for this . like :

```
<%= f.check_box :public, {}, true, false %>
```

output :

```
# <input id="event_public" name="event[public]" type="checkbox" value="true" />
```

Comment: Actually, the first thing you wrote has worked! (adding value="")

Comment: At least I thought so for a moment, then I broke something again. I am trying now this: `<%= survey_form.check_box :end_time_check, {:class => 'checkbox form-control show-toggle' , :data => { :target => "#end-time" }}, true, false %>` and still with checked checkbox the result is `nil`

Comment: the output is like this, but the variable is still `nil` after submitting